# I need to link my user to a certain file in header.php

Tags: php

I have a header.php file. That header.php file is included in many directories.

Some of them are:

`index.php` files in public_html

`index.php` files in public_html/user
`index.php` files in public_html/users4
`index.php` files in public_html/pro
`index.php` files in public_html/accaccess

The `index.php` file has a log out button. When I try to press the logout button (filename: `logout.php` and file location: `public_html`) from `public_html`, it logs out successfully. When I press logout from `public_html/user` or any other directories, so not from `public_html`, it says

> logout.php file not found.

The `logout.php` file is only in public_html, so I my `header.php` has linked the Log out text to the logout.php file in public_html.

However, it cannot find the file when I am pressing the button from files inside anoter directory.

So my question is, how do I make this work? How do I make it work so that no matter where you are, the log out button always works and it doesn't give me an error saying logout.php file not found?

Code for header.php

```
<?php
    if (loggedin()){
        ?>
    <body class="day-one-share day-one-login">

  <div class="grid-left group">
    <nav class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="linklist-admin">
        <li><a href="../pro">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="../pro/index4.php">My Entries</a></li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
 </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
    } else {
        ?>

         <body class="day-one-share day-one-login">

  <div class="grid-left group">
    <nav class="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="linklist-admin">
        <li><a href="../pro">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="../pro/index4.php">My Entries</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
 </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What should we fix? Your invisible code? (If yes this is the answer: `[nothing here]`)

Comment: Please put some examples of the code in your php file (that logs the user out).

Comment: Relative URLs are relative to the current URL. If you're just making a link `<a href="logout.php">`, then that URL will resolve to different URLs depending on the "folder" you're currently in. Use *absolute URLs*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute URL's. It's that simple, really.